# Can two components be abstract in Angular2 Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have three components:

1. Root component (`root`) that is a component bootstraps with app
   module.
2. Toolbar component (`toolbar`) that contains toolbar for
   all it's children.
3. Dashboard component (`dashboard`) that is
   first real page.

So the `root` and `toolbar` should not have it's own URL, and `dashboard` should. At the resulting HTML I expect that they are put into 
each other in the following way:

```
<root>
  <toolbar>
    ...some toolbar inner code
    <dashboard>
      ...dashboard page code
    </dashboard>
  </toolbar>
</root>
```

And all of this code should be loaded by single URL: http:///dashboard

Now I have following code:

`root` module routing

```typescript
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: ToolbarComponent},
];
```

`toolbar` module routing

```typescript
const toolbarRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
];
```

It works, but replaces `toolbar` component with `dashboard`.

How should I write my `Routes` arrays to fulfil this demand? With `ui-router` and deprecated `component router` on AngularJS I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `router-outlet` in `ToolbarComponent`'s template

And your route config will be like

```
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '',
      component: ToolbarComponent,
      children: {
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
      }
];
```

Now `/dashboard` will render both Toolbar and Dashboard